# How to build a service which returns an Observable?

Tags: angular

I am building a service which queries Google Maps Places Autocomplete API and returns an array of objects. The service itself is pretty straightforward. I am using the Maps JS API. A string is passed to the service, and it returns the list of matches.

The problem is how to make this service output into an Angular Observable?

This is where I am now:

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
declare var google: any;

@Injectable()
export class GoogleMapsService {

    getAutocomplete(input = {'input': '', 'types': [] } ) {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
        return autocomplete.getPlacePredictions({ input: input.input });
    }
}
```

But this is not an Observable, and I can't `.subscribe` to it.

Comment: What *is* it, then? If it's a promise, use `Observable.fromPromise`.

Comment: with the returned data you need to plot them on map?

Comment: No, there is no map, it's just an autocomplete input for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the documentation said that autocomplete.getPlacePredictions has two params: request and callback function. So you can do:

```
Observable.create(obs => {
  let displaySuggestions = function (predictions, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      obs.error(status);
    }
    else {
      obs.next(predictions);
      obs.complete();
    }
  };

  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  service.getQueryPredictions({input: 'test'}, displaySuggestions);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the example in the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction) for `getQueryPredictions`:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
service.getQueryPredictions({ input: 'pizza near Syd' }, displaySuggestions);
```

it expects the last argument to be a callback that receives the results. `getPlacePredictions` is presumably the same. This suggests that you can use [`Observable.bindCallback`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback) as follows:

```
return Observable.bindCallback(autocomplete.getPlacePredictions)({ input: input.input });
```

Note that `bindCallback` returns a function that takes the same arguments as the wrapped function, minus the callback.

Comment: Observable.fromCallback() doesn't seem to exist in Angular.

Comment: @TamásPolgár which version of RxJS are you using (see your `package.json`)? What error are you getting, and from where?

Comment: rxjs 5.0.1, rx 4.0.1. Angular says: "Property 'fromCallback' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.)"

Comment: @TamásPolgár apparently it's called [`bindCallback`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback), editing...

Comment: This totally doesn't work. All I am getting is a ton of mysterious error messages. "Supplied parameters do not match signature of call target." No matter what I specify as parameter, this one persists.

Comment: @TamásPolgár from so little information, there's not much I can do. Could you make a [mcve] in a Plunkr or something?

Comment: I will, but let me try to figure it out first. I'll never learn all this mess if I don't do my research. I'll return here if I can't get anywhere. Thanks for the guidance.